# Wordpress - Media Gallery An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am working on customized WP Theme and was on verge of finalization. But all of sudden my laptop got shutdown and then after I got the error message & opted to repair *wp_options*, which I did and now on trying to upload images I get error :

> An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later.

On checking, I found upload folder was READ ONLY - which I changed. Images are getting uploaded to the folder but it does not show in Media Library. I even tried Twenty Seventeen - but no luck.

Please advise.

Thanks in advance,

Vikram

Comment: Please double check your folder permission. please make 755 permission.
Also please check your file size it is under max_upload_size.

Comment: Yes -  permission is set to 755 and for testing purpose, am trying to upload files of hardly few kbs - but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try deactivating and reactivating your plugins one by one to see if there is a conflict from a plugin?

Wordpress returns this error for a number of reasons. To investigate it further, you can do the following:

- In Chrome or Firefox press F12 and go to Network tab.
- Try to upload image again so it triggers the error.
- At the bottom left of Developer Tools/Console find async_upload.php file name and click it.
- Go to Preview tab. This will show you the error details.

Let us know what error are you seeing so we can attempt to fix it.

Comment: Wow!!! It worked like a charm. All the plugins were de-activated & again activated. Superb. 

What could be the issue? Laptop just crashed.

Comment: @Vikram It must have been a file conflict. Glad it worked out.

Comment: Possibilities of file conflict  - very true - Thank you Hamza & Jagir ...

Answer (score 0):

I inspected  the Source of the page and discovered this below is the error,

DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for https://sfcui.org.ng/wp-content/plugins/wp-user-manager/vendor/htmlburger/carbon-fields/assets/dist/carbon.core.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

The plugin WP User Manager is the one affecting script from loading the ajax request. I deactivated it and I was able to upload.